# Which experimental procedures exist for determining the elemental composition of a nanostructure?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, nanoscience, elements

I am doing nanostructures on semiconductors with focused-ion beam lithography, and I am interested to know if the elemental composition is changed at the surface where the sputtering occurred. Originally I wanted to do XPS measurements, but the guy in charge of the lab just told me today that the lateral resolution is 60µm max, while my structures are usually 1µm wide. Of course I could go a bit higher if really needed but 60µm is way too large. Moreover the point is to study the nanostructures themselves, since it could behave differently for bigger structures.

Do you guys have a suggestion of what I could do instead?

Thank you very much in advance.

Julien.

Comment: Electron microprobe (x-ray spectroscopy in an SEM) would be a good bet.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks for your answer. Is that basically what is known as EDX?

Comment: Yes. It is pretty common.

Comment: Great I will look into it!